# Why do chefs use salt and pepper bowl after touching raw foods

Tags: food-safety

When I see chefs on tv handling raw chicken or such and then stick their fingers in a salt bowl to seasoning them why is the salt in the bowl not contaminated too. I see this all the time on cooking shows.